# How to change texbox by a combobox in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-lightswitch

Hi i'm learning Visual Studio LightSwitch, I have a table Device with two rows: name of Device and foreing key to a Computer table, LightSwitch generate a view to add new device, i want to change the behavior of the texbox do the device name field to act like a combobox and fill the combobox with some data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a device entity (table) and replace the "name" property in the table or create a screen string property as a choice list and equate it to your device name on save?
Something like:

this.device.name = this.deviceselect.name

Scott